# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RTCPeerConnection'

Tags: angular, typescript, webrtc, typescript2.0

I am using WebRTC in Angular 2.

In **TypeScript 1.x**, I can use this successfully.

```
const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, null);
```

But after updating to **TypeScript 2.x**, I got this error in my terminal:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RTCPeerConnection'.

I already did `npm install --save-dev @types/webrtc`, and my IDE WebStorm already link it to the typing of `RTCPeerConnection` correctly.

Typing of `RTCPeerConnection` is in /my-project/node_modules/@types/webrtc/RTCPeerConnection.d.ts

My **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@types/webrtc` is a global type definition. Add

```
"types": [
  "webrtc"
]
```

to your `compilerOptions`. The `types` option is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Compiler%20Options.md).