# TS2304: Cannot find name 'RTCErrorEvent'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webrtc, quasar

I'm implementing a WebRTC app using Quasar, typescript and Vue. This piece of code does not yield any error in WebStorm (uses project's eslint config), I can go to `RTCErrorEvent` definition in DOM API file (`lib.dom.d.ts`):

```js
  handleDataChannelError(error: RTCErrorEvent) {
    console.log('dataChannel.OnError:', error);
  }
```

However when I run the application via `quasar dev` or try to build it with `quasar build` I get an error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'RTCErrorEvent'`. Running esling via lint task `eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue ./` yields no errors as well.

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908860/error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-rtcpeerconnection) with installing `@types/webrtc` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061266/can-i-import-dom-types-explicitly) (adding to `quasar.d.ts`), with no effect. I've checked and `node_modules/@types/webrtc` does not contain this class.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

In Quasar CLI [docs](https://quasar.dev/start/quasar-cli#whats-included) in can find only this bit which explains how the dev server works...

> While developing with Dev Server ($ quasar dev):
>
> - Babel, so you can write ES6 code
> - Webpack + vue-loader for Vue SFC (single file components)
> - State preserving hot-reload
> - State preserving compilation error overlay
> - Lint-on-save with ESLint
> - Source maps
> - Develop right on a device emulator (or a real phone connected to your machine) if you target a Mobile App
> - ...

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Should I dug deeper into `quasar.conf.js` or `babel.config.js`? Also, interestingly I cannot locate `lib.dom.d.ts` file in project files. How can I check which version/file of DOM API is used by Quasar dev server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `webrtc` to the `compilerOptions.types` property of `tsconfig.json` ?